# Connecting MySQL to server through another server by SSH

Tags: ssh

Setup:

- My computer (linux / unix) has an arbitrary IP address
- I can connect to a central linux server which has a static ip
- Remote linux systems are set up so they only respond to central server IP address on port 22

I want to port forward through the central server so I can use MySQLWorkbench and make python scripting connections on port 3306 to the remote systems.

Ideally, I would like the syntax for `ssh` command to make the port forwarding work;

Suppose I want to forward local port 3307 to 3306 on the remote system. Assume my ip is `x.x.x.x`, the central server IP is `y.y.y.y`, and the remote system IP is `z.z.z.z`;

I *think* it has something to do with `ssh -L` but I can only forward to the central server so far. Maybe I need to connect to the central server, set up forwarding there, then set up forwarding on my machine? I *think* functionality exists to do it with a single command using `ssh`.

If this is a duplicate, it should not be marked as such because without knowing what magic keyword to search for, you can't find the duplicate;

Clarification: port 3306 is NOT open on the remote server. Only 22

Comment: I'm also thinking the answer will be generic across any -nix system since ssh is same between linux and unix..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -L :3307:z.z.z.z:3306 user@y.y.y.y -Nf
```

Works fine

or

```
ssh -L 3307:z.z.z.z:3306 user@y.y.y.y  -Nf
```

To only bind to `x.x.x.x`'s localhost

The first example binds to all interfaces

edit...

Just seen that `z.z.z.z` only has port 22 open.

on `y.y.y.y` you will also need to have a local port open

run on y.y.y.y

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@z.z.z.z -Nf
```

then on x.x.x.x

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3307 user@y.y.y.y -Nf
```

run these commands in a screen for best results

You can actually condense these 2 commands together

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3307 user@y.y.y.y -f 'ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@z.z.z.z -Nf'
```

Comment: Had to `cat` `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from `y.y.y.y` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `z.z.z.z`. And where you have "`::`" it should be "`:`", and your last command works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -L <local-port-to-listen>:<remote-host>:<remote-port>

The ‘L’ switch indicates that a local port forward is need to be created
```

Best method is to create the tunnel using putty (ssh client). so you can start the shell, and it will create the ssh tunnel for you. this is a good reference

https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/